# How to unset a field in views?

Tags: 7, views

How can I unset a view field based on value of some other field in the same view ?
I cant use views php module ? 
Is there any other option for it?

Answer (score 2):

use [hook_view_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) and in this, you need to check for that value in if condition...

Comment: your answer is right but what I want to place the condition using the views UI .Is there anyway I can do by changing something in the edit view itself ?

Comment: if you are willing to do so, there is i think only one way ie to inject php code in views but i dont prefer this because site is too buggy and hacker will take advantage of this one.
:)

Comment: Actually I have added a global custom text field and I am unable to alter the html of that field in the template.php file using theme_name_process_views_view_field(&$vars). So I tried directly inserting html into text field of 'edit view' .Can u tell me how to insert html into global custom text field which is fields['nothing'] ?